# Notation for set of $n$-simplices in a simplicial complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Let $K$ be a simplicial complex. Is there a commonly used notation for the set of all $n$-simplices of $K$?

$K_n$ looks natural, but is $K_n$ already meaning something else?

I learn of the notation $sk_n$ meaning the $n$-skeleton of $K$. So basically, I am finding a neat notation for $sk_n-sk_{n-1}$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's anything standard, but you could use $${K \choose n}.$$

My reasoning is this.

If $X$ is a set, then it make sense to define that $${X \choose n} = \{A \subseteq X : |A|=n\}.$$

That way, we have:

$$\left|{X \choose n}\right| = {|X| \choose n}$$ where the RHS is the usual binomial coefficient of natural numbers.

Now by an *abstract simplicial complex*, lets mean an ordered pair $(X,E)$ where $X$ is a set and $E$ is a collection of subsets of $X$. Usually the empty subset is excluded from consideration, but lets allow it to be included. By the way, in graph theory these are called [hypergraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph). (The definition of hypergraphs also typically excludes $\emptyset$ just like in algebraic topology. Again, for the purposes of this question lets allow it to be an element of $E$.)

It makes sense to define that if $K = (X,E)$ is a hypergraph (abstract simplicial complex, whatever), then $${K \choose n} = \{A \in E : |A| = n\}.$$

The reason is this. Each set $X$ naturally associated with two corresponding hypergraphs, namely $(X,\{\})$ and $(X,\{A \subseteq X\}).$ The latter is a bit more useful/natural, so it's convenient to identify $X$ with $(X,\{A \subseteq X\}).$ In light of this identification, we observe that $${X \choose n} = {(X,\{A \subseteq X\}) \choose n} = \{B \in \{A \subseteq X\} : |B| = n\} = \{B \subseteq X : |B| = n\},$$ which agrees with our previous definition.

**Remark.** You could upgrade the notation to include $k$-skeletons as well. Whenever $p$ is a predicate on the natural numbers, define

$${K \choose p} = \{A \in K : p(|A|)\}.$$

Then $${K \choose \Box = n} = {K \choose n}, \qquad {K \choose \Box \leq n} = sk_n(K).$$

Answer (score 2):

The standard and universal notation is, indeed, $K_n$.

Comment: Just to check, is $K^n$ an acceptable notation or does it mean something else? I find that I need to use $K_1, K_2, \dots$ to index different simplicial complexes.

Comment: @yoyostein $K^n$ would be the $n$-fold product, or alternatively denote the fact that you are looking at the $n$th component of a **co**simplicial set. I really wouldn't go against convention for this. You can write $(K_1)_n$ for example.